# Opposite of racism?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Last week, I was on a political group on FB and someone mentioned this word. When I looked it up, its definitions indicated it was the opposite of racism. The word means, in simple terms, that "Person A feels racially inferior to Person B and perhaps even wants to be the race of Person B". It starts with an "m" I think.

Comment: But that *is* racism. They feel that the *other* race is "better," and, so, wish they could be of that race. The actual opposite of racism could be inclusivity.

Comment: Could it be "Racial Envy"?

Comment: If B is the dominant race in that society, we'd call that *internalized racism*. (For example, many American blacks will agree with various socially pervasive negative stereotypes about blacks, because they're almost as awash in those stereotypes as everyone else, so they've *internalized* them.)

Comment: Hmm... If there is indeed a word with that kind of a meaning (it's **not** quite the opposite of *racism* by the way)! *Fascination*?

Comment: I think the word you’re looking for might be “ethnomasochism.”

Comment: If you looked it up last week, might it not still be in your History? If it really isn't, please change your History settings ASAP".

Answer (score 0):

One word that fits is **supremacist**:

> An advocate of the supremacy of a particular group, especially one determined by race or sex.
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/supremacist)</sub>

While it's usually used for people who believe their own race is superior to others, it's also used with people who aren't that race. For example, one might call someone a black White supremacist or a white Black supremacist, although there is apparently another (likely pretty offensive) [term for the former](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cracker%20black) (see LaShanda's definition).

---

In addition there are other words that fit but are more about hating one's own race rather than liking a certain other race:

- Self hating (also "self hatred". For example "Black Self-Hatred" in [this title](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/charles-cole-iii/orville-douglas-black-self-hatred_b_4279216.html).)
- [Internalized racism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internalized_racism)